# google calendar api fatal error reading event with id

Tags: events, calendar

So I'm syncing an appointment application with google calendar.
I create the events, successfully, and store the id of the event in a table.

Later, if I need to update the event, I can just use that event id to update the correct event, instead of scanning through all the calendar events.

But for one record, the api crashes with a fatal error, stating the event doesn't exist.

When I do a scan through the records with the api, I see the event with the same event id that I'm trying to update.

What is going on?

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event($apptarray);

$event->setSummary($apptarray['summary']);
$event->description = $apptarray['description'];
$event->location = $apptarray['location'];
$event->start->dateTime = $apptarray['start']['dateTime'];
$event->end->dateTime = $apptarray['end']['dateTime'];            
$newevent = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
```

Then I'm storing $newevent->id in a table.

Later :

```
//$calendarId is the event->id coming in from the table, and I've verify it's correct.
// it also works for the other appointments I've done in the same calendar and the same call but different $calendarId.
$event = $service->events->get('primary', $eventId);
$event->setSummary($apptarray['summary']);
$event->description = $apptarray['description'];
$event->location = $apptarray['location'];
$event->start->dateTime = $apptarray['start']['dateTime'];
$event->end->dateTime = $apptarray['end']['dateTime'];

$updatedEvent = $service->events->update('primary', $event->getId(), $event);
```

Any ideas?

Edit:  the error I'm getting on this is:

Edit2: corrected spelling of appointments and changed $calendarId to $eventId to make it more clear. That function *was* using calendarid as the eventid but I changed it here to make it less confusing as to what I'm passing.
 
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET     https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/primary: (404) Not Found' in C:\sss\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:110 Stack trace: #0

Comment: Can you share logs on what the error is? Checking on your code snippets, I don't see any issue with it aside from you only specifically updating `dateTime`. Try to update the whole `start` and `end` objects and see if it will have the same error.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/primary: (404) Not Found' in C:\sss\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:110 Stack trace: #0

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/primary:  you have an extra primary on the end which I don't think belongs there.   Tip: use patch instead of update.

Comment: Well, the documentation at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update is 
    $updatedEvent = $service->events->update('primary', $event->getId(), $event);  so I'm not sure.  But my error is occurring on the GET command, not the UPDATE anyway.